# C# Excel Change Char Color

Tags: c#, winforms, mfc, winforms-interop

I want to change all red characters to blue characters in the Excel file and then save it.

I kept trying, but the method seemed to be wrong and didn't work..

Please advise.

```
color = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Characters[k,1].Font.Color;
if(color == Color.Red)
{
     xlRange.Cells[i, j].Characters[k, 1].Font.Color = Color.Blue;
}
```

I just want to get the color of each character, change it, and save it, but no matter what I do, it doesn't work.

Thank you.

I've attached the more code below.

After opening excel I tried to read the colors.

However, it doesn't behave as desired.

Please advise..

```
//Create COM Objects. Create a COM object for everything that is referenced
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

int nSheetNo = 3;

Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@SelectedFilePath);
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[nSheetNo];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

int rowCount = 10;// xlRange.Rows.Count;
int colCount = 10;// xlRange.Columns.Count;

double color;

for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
    {
        if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
        {
            strSentence = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Characters;
            if (strSentence is not null)
            {
                LenSentence = strSentence.Count;

                for (int k = 0; k < strSentence.Count; k++)
                {
                    color = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Characters[k,1].Font.Color;
                    if(color == Color.Red)
                    {
                        xlRange.Cells[i, j].Characters[k, 1].Font.Color = Color.Blue;
                    }
                }

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. use debugger to figure out if conditions passed, for instance `color == Color.Red`, check if it actually worked and `= Color.Blue` was run. 2. did you save the excel after editing? not familiar with this library so dunno if you need to specifically save after editing though. 3. Is this the correct way to change the color of a certain character? Won't the font be shared? you need to check that too.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of your code is color values conversion.

I hope the code below will be helpful for you

```
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = false;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@SelectedFilePath);
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        for (int i = 1; i <= xlRange.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= xlRange.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if ((xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null) && (xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null))
                {
                    if (xlRange.Cells[i, j].Characters != null)
                    {
                        for (int k = 1; k <= xlRange.Cells[i, j].Characters.Count; k++)
                        {
                            int color = Convert.ToInt32(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Characters(k, 1).Font.Color);

                            if (ColorTranslator.FromOle(color) == Color.Red)
                                xlRange.Cells[i, j].Characters(k, 1).Font.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Blue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        xlWorkbook.Save();
        xlApp.Visible = true;
```